# Start and terminate subprocess from python function

Tags: python, subprocess

How do I write a function that can start and kill a subrocess in python??

this is my code so far:

```
import subprocess
import signal
import time

def myfunction(action):
    if action == 'start':
        print 'Start subrocess'
        process = subprocess.Popen("ping google.com", shell=True)
    if action == 'stop':
        print 'Stop subrocess'
        process.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)

myfunction('start')
time.sleep(10)
myfunction('stop')
```

When I run this code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    myfunction('stop')
  File "test.py", line 11, in myfunction
    process.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'process' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: variable process is destroyed once function is executed. QuickFix is global variables or OOP.

Comment: woah there @Serge, don't be so quick to suggest global variables! in this case especially, there are many other quick fixes to go to first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn OOP and define MyClass with constructor and destructor.
Assuming you do not need run many copies of process, and to make it more exotic we can use class methods

```
class MyClass(object):
    @classmethod
    def start(self)
        print 'Start subrocess'
        self.process = subprocess.Popen("ping google.com", shell=True)

    @classmethod
    def stop(self)
        self.process.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)

MyClass.start()
MyClass.stop()
```

This not ideal as it allows you to create several new processes.
Quite often in such cases singleton pattern is used, that insures there is only one process is running yet it is a bit out of fashion.

The minimal fix (keeping myfunction) is to save process in a variable:

```
import subprocess
import signal
import time

def myfunction(action, process=None):
    if action == 'start':
        print 'Start subrocess'
        process = subprocess.Popen("ping google.com", shell=True)
        return process
    if action == 'stop':
        print 'Stop subrocess'
        process.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)

process = myfunction('start')
time.sleep(10)
myfunction('stop', process)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to save your subprocess variable and pass it into the function. when you call `myfunction('stop')`, there's nowhere for the function scope to get `process` from (thus the `UnboundLocalError`).

Without the function scope, this should work fine - which shows that your issue is with function scope and not really with process handling:

```
print 'Start subrocess'
process = subprocess.Popen("ping google.com", shell=True)
time.sleep(10)
print 'Stop subprocess'
process.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem you are having is due to the fact that `process` is declared as a local variable within `myfunction`, and in particular only within the `'start'` if statement. This small scope means that when you call `myfunction('stop')`, the function has no notion of the 'process' variable.

There are several ways around this, but the most intuitive would be for `myfunction` to return `process` when one was made, and take one as a parameter when you want to close it. The code would look something like:

```
import subprocess
import signal
import time


def myfunction(action, process=None):
    if action == 'start':
        print 'Start subrocess'
        process = subprocess.Popen("ping google.com", shell=True)
        return process       
    if action == 'stop':
        print 'Stop subrocess'
        process.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM)



process = myfunction('start')
time.sleep(10)
myfunction('stop', process)
```

I have just ran this in 2.7.13 and it works fine